# Amazon Corretto 11 32 bits

Tags: java, windows, 32-bit, corretto

Our java application is running on Windows platform and it uses 32 bit Windows dlls (which are difficult to port to 64 bit).

Is there any chance a Windows x86 release can be provided for Amazon Corretto 11 (like Corretto 8)?

Please advise. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's a question for Amazon

Answer (score 0):

Since JDK 9, almost all available JDKs are 64 bit only. [Azul Systems](https://www.azul.com/) had a JDK 10 32-bit for Windows that I downloaded and used, however when I searched the Internet just now, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Yes, Oracle only provides 64 bit JDK since JDK 9. However, I really hope that Amazon can support 32 bit Windows binaries after JDK 8.